# How would a mass hibernation on a set schedule effect a society's development?

Tags: society, hibernation

So I have this idea for a world where there are two major groups of sentients. For the purposes of this question, we'll call them the Protags and the Antags. The Protags are active during the 'Long Sleep' or hibernation of the Antags, and vice versa. I have not finalized the length of the hibernation of the two groups, but for the time being we'll say that they both hibernate for a year.

Now you might be asking, "what are the Protags and the Antags? Are they human?" To answer the question, the Protags might just be humans, but I am leaning towards them being a mix of humanoids (humans, elves, dwarves etc.), and sentient animals, plants/fungi and objects. The Antags are not humans, but are most likely going to be humanoid giants.

So how would this hibernation effect the society of the Protags? How long would it take them to develop a level of technology that we have now? Is it realistically possible?

Comment: Is it realistically possible - such things are usually associated with posts having a [tag:reality-check] tag, whereas what you seem to be more aiming at here is [tag:fantasy] based. Also, can you narrow it a bit, at present you have the three questions, since we only deal with one at a time, why not [edit] down to establishing a basis for the behavior first, then ask more questions in their own threads, depending on what you decide after reading the answers to this?

Comment: I have to say "how would x affect the development " could get somewhat opinion based without very many more details added. We'd need detailed run-down on how their societies functioned, the capabilities and much other stuff, and even then there would be so-many culture-specific and environment-specific possibilities. More specific and answerable ways of asking would be appreciated. On thing I might add, their 1 year-olds would need to be strong and fat to survive the next hibernation cycle after their birth, so they'd be fast growing and need lots of grub.

Comment: Greetings!  Excellent basis for a potential series of excellent questions! As the others have said, as it's written, your query lack focus. It's in the close queue which means that it will be "frozen" -- no answers can be given -- until you improve it to meet community standards. In this case, you'll need to focus on *some aspect of society* rather than just on society as a whole. Take a moment to check out our [tour] and [help]. You've already got a good idea [what Worldbuilding is all about!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about)!